# How to host and use a webservice in Java tomcat and called by application written with AngularJs?

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, cordova, tomcat

I have in mind to develop a smartphone application using Cordova and AngularJs. This application needs to communicate with a database, so I would like to develop a webservice using a RESTful API, which will be called by my application in AngularJs, and based on a Java Tomcat server.

**My first question is :**
When my application will be ready to be published on the market, how can I host my webservice ? Is it like hosting a website ?

Moreover, I will use my webservice like this with AngularJs :

```
var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);

services.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/users', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {},
      isArray: false
    }
  })
});
```

source : http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/

But, I should replace the url '/ngdemo/rest/users' by the url provided by hosting, right ?

**So, my second question is :**
This url is public and everyone have access to it, is it not a security issue ? It means that anyone can access to method GET, PUT, POST ... ? Or I have to develop a permissions system in my webservice ?

Thank you so much for your time and your response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting a tomcat server running a java webservice is exactly like hosting a website. Tomcat is a type of web server.

Unless you want everyone to be able to access your entire REST application you need to put some kind of permission system on the server. There are countless way of doing this. The simplest is to send a username and password in an authorization header (aka basic auth) and check the username and password in your servlet against user credentials you store in your database.